# Java Outer Class Instance Lifetime

Tags: java, class, nested, instance, parent

I am lacking understanding of the following: if I create an instance of an inner class using "shorthand," is it a bad idea to access the outer class even though I created no explicit instance of it?

For example, consider the following code:

```
class OuterClass
{
    int i;

    OuterClass() { i = 2; }

    class InnerClass
    {
        int get_parent_i() { return (OuterClass.this.i); }
    }
}
```

The following compiles and returns the expected result (2):

```
OuterClass.InnerClass ic = new OuterClass().new InnerClass();

System.out.println(ic.get_parent_i());
```

My confusion stems from the fact that I didn't explicitly create an OuterClass object in order to instantiate an InnerClass object, although one seems to exist regardless. Can someone tell me what is going on, and if I should for any reason either access or forget about the phantom instance?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What did you think `new OuterClass()` does if not explicitly create an instance of it? :)

You did not explicitly *store a reference to it*, but that is a different thing.  Invoking the constructor makes an instance, regardless of what you do with the result.  The inner class has a built in `$this` reference back to the outer class, so there will always be a reference to it kept around as long as you keep the inner class.

Whether using an inner class is *ever* a good idea is a historically contentious topic, but there's nothing specifically wrong with that particular usage.

Answer (score -1):

The first block of your code is 100% acceptable and correct. Yet this pattern is often used as an internal mechanism of a huge Outer Class (eg an Internal Factory).

regarding the second block of your code. You don't need to create an object of the OuterClass if you make both (inner & outer class) public visible. This way The InnerClass is visible to the rest packages without touching the OuterClass.

Yet, if you do that in your example you would have a NullPointerException, since you are using parts of the Outerclass the (i).

Moreover,  if you had.

```
public class OuterClass
{
    static int i;

    static {
        i = 3;
    }

    OuterClass() { i = 2; }

    public class InnerClass
    {
        int get_parent_i() { return (OuterClass.this.i); }
    }
}
```

"i" would be equal to 3 unless you initiate the OuterClass in the future and changes its value to 2.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Static variables have nothing to do with how inner classes work, nor do they have anything to do with public/default visibility.

Comment: Mind sir: Static is an "almost" singleton pattern. Since that it has to do with every class no matter is inner or outer class in any package. 

Moreover, I tried to explain the behaviour of inner content. Showing that inner Content don't always has to effect the outer content. Except it faces a static content ( variable, Blocks, functions ).